# ANT - retrieving the current task name

Tags: ant, reference, task

How can an ANT task like this one:

```
<target name="mytask">
  <echo>processing ${blabla}</echo>
</target>
```

print `processing mytask` ?

What should I replace `blabla` with ? Or this is actually even possible ?

Comment: What's your use case?  Do you just need to print when a task starts/finishes, because Ant can do that already.

Comment: No, that was just an example. I want to create a file with the target name.

Comment: Is the file-creator in Ant or external (reading the output)?

Comment: It looks like you mean't target rather than task.

Comment: Seems a strange requirement. You want to know the name of the current target so you can use that value, in the same target, to do something (create a file). You are writing the target. It has a name. Type the name again within the body of the target. Why do you need to dynamically discover the name at runtime?

Comment: @sudocode - does this appear strange to you ? I would avoid writing the same code over and over and introduce a pattern for file creation based on task name. What's strange ?

Comment: I'm all for code reuse/abstraction in general, but for this case I was wondering how it could be worthwhile. If I compare this: `<target name="foobar"><currenttarget property="my_target"/><echo message="${my_target}"/></target>` with this `<target name="foobar"><echo message="foobar"/></target>` it's hard to see why the first is better. But I shouldn't make assumptions about your requirements. If it works for you, go for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you with vanilla Ant, if your version is recent enough to include javascript support.

```
<scriptdef name="currenttarget" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="property"/>
    <![CDATA[
    importClass( java.lang.Thread );

    project.setProperty(
        attributes.get( "property" ),
        project.getThreadTask(
            Thread.currentThread( ) ).getTask( ).getOwningTarget( ).getName( ) );
    ]]>
</scriptdef>

<target name="foobar">
    <currenttarget property="my_target" />
    <echo message="${my_target}" />
</target>
```

The `scriptdef` sets up a task `currenttarget` that can be used to get the current target in a property, which you can then use as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The task name is always output to console by Ant:

Here is an example:

```
<project default="test">

    <target name="test" depends="mytask-silent, mytask-echo"/>

    <target name="mytask-echo">
        <echo>processing</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="mytask-silent"/>

</project>
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\tmp\ant>ant
Buildfile: c:\tmp\ant\build.xml

mytask-silent:

mytask-echo:
     [echo] processing

test:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: This answers your original question, but not your actual requirement as updated in comments.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, but your answer does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know it do this is to write an ANT task or use a [groovy script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) as follows:

```
<target name="mytask" depends="init">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
        println "processing ${target}"
    </groovy>
</target>
```